# If i use multiple "if statements" then hitting error (Terminating app due to uncaught exception) in swift

Tags: swift, if-statement, uinavigationcontroller, cell

I am using `PopoverView` to show options in tableview cell button like [this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW4Un.png)

here if i use like this no error.. but if check conditions with `if statements`
then crash and error

```
 @objc func showOptions(sender:UIButton) {
   
    popoverView?.show(with: ["View", "View Proposal", "Delete"], sender: sender, showDirection: .up)
 }
```

**but here for each cell i need to show different options according to below conditions**

**code for cell button action**: here open, close, in progress.. all are segmented modes

```
    @objc func showOptions(sender:UIButton) {
   
    if mode == .Open{
        popoverView?.show(with: ["View", "View Proposal", "Delete"], sender: sender, showDirection: .up)
    }
    if (mode == .Open) && (bidsCount > 0){
        popoverView?.show(with: ["View", "View Proposal", "Edit", "Delete"], sender: sender, showDirection: .up)
    }
    if mode == .In_progress{
        popoverView?.show(with: ["View", "View Proposal", "Delete"], sender: sender, showDirection: .up)
    }
    if mode == .Awarded{
        popoverView?.show(with: ["View", "Delete"], sender: sender, showDirection: .up)
    }
    if mode == .Closed{
        popoverView?.show(with: ["View"], sender: sender, showDirection: .up)
    }
}
```

PopoverView code:

```
extension PageContentViewController: PopoverViewDelegate {
func value(didSelect item: String, at index: Int, indexPath: IndexPath, sender: UIView) {
    if item == "View" {
        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC1") as? VC1
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }
    if item == "View Proposal" {
        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2") as? VC2
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }
     if item == "Post Review" {
        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC3") as? VC3
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally a view controller <UITableViewController: 0x7fdb37092420> that is already being presented by <TestApp.SideMenuController: 0x7fdb36659370>.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if mode == .Open{
    popoverView?.show(with: ["View", "View Proposal", "Delete"], sender: sender, showDirection: .up)
}
if (mode == .Open) && (bidsCount > 0){
    popoverView?.show(with: ["View", "View Proposal", "Edit", "Delete"], sender: sender, showDirection: .up)
}
```

This presents a popover, and then presents a second popover, which is not allowed. Any time `(mode == .Open) && (bidsCount > 0)` is true, `mode == .Open` is also true.

You probably meant to reorder these and to use `else if` rather than just `if`.

Generally, however, this would be done with a `switch` statement, such as:

```
switch mode {
    case .Open where bidsCount > 0:
        ...
    case .Open:
        ...
    case .In_progress:
        ...
    ...
}
```

(Note that enum cases are generally camelcase in Swift. So these would traditionally be `.open` and `.inProgress`.)